# Python/Bash - Tab completion not including files when arguments are provided

Tags: python, bash

I'm not sure whether this is a Python issue or a bash issue, but I'm having trouble with tab completion not working on files (only directories) when I'm providing arguments to my python script. Example of how I want it to work:

```
python myscript.py -e data_dir/da[TAB]
python myscript.py -e data_dir/data.tsv
```

However, it works when I'm not providing an argument, or if I'm using an equals sign between the argument and the file path. Examples of scenarios where it works:

```
python myscript.py data_dir/da[TAB]
python myscript.py data_dir/data.tsv

python myscript.py -e=data_dir/da[TAB]
python myscript.py data_dir/data.tsv
```

Is what I'm expecting unreasonable, considering the normal behavior of python and bash? I.e. is my tab completion working like it's supposed to? Alternatively, am I using python arguments incorrectly when I'm not including the equals sign with my arguments?

I'm using bash version 4.3.11(1)-release and python version 2.7.6.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what's wrong there, I'm assuming you have somehow messed up your completions. On bash 4.3.42(1)-release I got tab completion in all cases (with no changes made whatsoever to my .bashrc etc.)

Comment: I have the same behaviour. As mentionned [here](http://false.ekta.is/2013/07/bash-tab-completion-for-python-scripts/), it appears that **folder** names however continue to be completed... After a few tests, it works again when you use a long arg like `--long-arg` instead of a short one. Strange behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is truly weird.